# Library ecCodes not founded by Python, but the selfcheck of the library works

Tags: python, eccodes

I am developing a code to analyze some weather data and using the ecCodes library to read the files. On linux Ubuntu it works perfectly, but on AWS Linux, for some reason, the OS aren't able to find the ecCodes library. I am sure that the library is correctly installed, because the selfcheck of ecCodes are returning "OK" and I am able to import eccodes while to execute Python command lines.
Here follows the error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acY7V.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste the full stack into the question body for easier accessibility.